# What is the Biblical basis for God's divine decree in Scripture (Calvinism)?

Tags: biblical-basis, reformed-theology, will-of-god

I have listened to Calvinists state that all that happens in time is a result of God's divine decree. Where in Scripture do we find evidence for the existence of such a decree, or where in Scripture can the existence of such a decree be inferred?

Comment: +1 just for making me google it and find this: http://www.sounddoctrine.net/Bible/Berkof_7.htm  Short, but good reading.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking but to speak like Calvin you would have to limit 'all' to something more than the mundane. I would not say it is calvinistic to say it was 'God's decree' that you ate a Big Mac yesterday, but as God is all powerful of course you could not eat at McDonalds without God permitting it. Also nothing you eat at McDonald's could frustrate God's decreed eternal plan of redeeming the elect through Christ.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am a Calvinist, but perhaps these may be some examples:

[Isaiah 14:24](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Isa&c=14&v=1&t=KJV#conc/24)

The LORD of hosts hath sworn, saying, Surely as I have thought, so shall it come to pass; and as I have purposed, [so] shall it stand:

[Isaiah 14:27](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Isa&c=14&v=1&t=KJV#conc/27)

For the LORD of hosts hath purposed, and who shall disannul [it]? and his hand [is] stretched out, and who shall turn it back?